# How do I dynamically list a nested object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the code that should display a movie's cast when the user selects a movie from a drop down list.

No matter what movie is selected, it is always the cast of the last movie that is displayed ("Fantastic Mr. Fox"). I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```js
let movieData = {
    "The Darjeeling Limited": {
      plot: "A year after their father's funeral, three brothers travel across India by train in an attempt to bond with each other.",
      cast: ["Jason Schwartzman", "Owen Wilson", "Adrien Brody"],
      runtime: 151,
      rating: 7.2,
      year: 2007,
    },
    "The Royal Tenenbaums": {
      plot: "The eccentric members of a dysfunctional family reluctantly gather under the same roof for various reasons",
      rating: 7.6,
      year: 2001,
      cast: ["Gene Hackman", "Gwnyeth Paltrow", "Anjelica Huston"],
      runtime: 170,
    },
    "Fantastic Mr. Fox": {
      year: 2009,
      plot: "An urbane fox cannot resist returning to his farm raiding ways and then must help his community survive the farmers' retaliation.",
      cast: [
        "George Clooney",
        "Meryl Streep",
        "Bill Murray",
        "Jason Schwartzman",
      ],
      runtime: 147,
      rating: 7.9,
    },
    "The Grand Budapest Hotel": {
      rating: 8.1,
      runtime: 159,
      year: 2014,
      plot: "A writer encounters the owner of an aging high-class hotel, who tells him of his early years serving as a lobby boy in the hotel's glorious years under an exceptional concierge.",
      cast: ["Ralph Fiennes", "F. Murray Abraham", "Mathieu Amalric"],
    },
  };
  //Practising data retrieval
  console.log(movieData);
  console.log(movieData["Fantastic Mr. Fox"]);
  console.log(movieData["Fantastic Mr. Fox"].year);
  console.log(movieData["Fantastic Mr. Fox"]['year']);
  console.log(movieData["Fantastic Mr. Fox"].cast[1]);
  
  // let object = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
  // console.log(object);
  // let object2 = document.getElementById("test");
  // console.log(object2);
  
  //Practising data render
  // let foxYear = movieData["Fantastic Mr. Fox"]['year'];
  
  // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = foxYear;
  
  //Practising object conversion
  let a = Object.keys(movieData);
  let b = Object.values(movieData);
  let c = Object.entries(movieData);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  
  //Rendering movie names to html page
  const movieListNames = Object.keys(movieData);
  console.log(movieListNames);
  //Passing in an array of movie names as a parameter
  function addSpaceToName(array) {
    for (let movie = 1; movie < array.length; movie++) {
      array[movie] = " " + array[movie]; 
    }
    return array;
  }
  addSpaceToName(movieListNames);
  document.getElementById("movie-list").innerHTML = movieListNames;
  
  function dropDown(movieName) {
    moviesDropDown.addEventListener('change', movieNameKey => {
      movieDetails.innerHTML = movieName;
      console.log(movieName)
    })}
  
  const movieDetails = document.getElementById('movie-details');
  
  // experimenting with an array
  movieDataArray = Object.entries(movieData);
  for (let i in movieDataArray) {
    console.log(movieDataArray[i]);
  };
  //drop down list
  //get element by id
  const moviesDropDown = document.getElementById('movies-drop-down');
  // for...in loop (for enumerable object)
  for (let movieName in movieData) {
    //create option element
    let movieOptionElement = document.createElement("option");
    //set the value of the "*value* attribute" (of the option element) to movieName key (of object)
    movieOptionElement.setAttribute('value', movieData[movieName]);
    //text to be display in drop down list is movieName key
    let movieOptionText = document.createTextNode(movieName);
    //add to option element
    movieOptionElement.appendChild(movieOptionText);
    //add to select element
    moviesDropDown.appendChild(movieOptionElement);
  
    dropDown(movieData[movieName]["cast"])
  };
  
  //display details when selected from drop down list
  /* moviesDropDown.addEventListener('change', movieNameKey => {
    movieDetails.innerHTML = movieNameKey.target.value;
    console.log(movieNameKey.target);
  }); */
  
  const newMovie = document.getElementById('new-movie');
```

```html
Movie list: <span id="movie-list"></span>
Select a movie: <select id="movies-drop-down"></select><br>
movie-details: <span id="movie-details"></span>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/1169519

Comment: what is the question about? what does not work?

Comment: Can you add your HTML also ? I can help with that...

Comment: I have inserted a Stack Snippet with a minimal HTML to make it run. I also rephrased your question to clarify what is not working (telling us what works is not really of interest). Please check and update if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you expect to display the movie's cast when the user selects a movie from the dropdown.

These are the issues with it:

- You call the function `dropDown` once for each movie, but then each time assign an event handler on the `<select>` element. That is not right: you should only listen *once* to a user-selection, not 4 times. So `dropDown` should only be called once -- outside of the loop.
- `dropDown` cannot get as argument the movie that will be selected, as you just cannot know **now** what a user may select in some **future**. So this function should take no arguments.
- The `change` event handler should inspect which value the user had taken, so it should look at `moviesDropDown.value`. However, for that to work, you need to fix the next issue:
- The `value` attribute of the `<option>` elements is not set correctly. Your code currently sets that attribute value to an *object*, to `movieData[movieName]`, but that will be stringified to `[object Object]` which is useless information. Instead you should set that attribute value to: `movieName`.

Not a problem, but that function `addSpaceToName` is overkill. You can achieve this with the native array method `join`.

With these corrections it should work:

```js
let movieData = {
    "The Darjeeling Limited": {
      plot: "A year after their father's funeral, three brothers travel across India by train in an attempt to bond with each other.",
      cast: ["Jason Schwartzman", "Owen Wilson", "Adrien Brody"],
      runtime: 151,
      rating: 7.2,
      year: 2007,
    },
    "The Royal Tenenbaums": {
      plot: "The eccentric members of a dysfunctional family reluctantly gather under the same roof for various reasons",
      rating: 7.6,
      year: 2001,
      cast: ["Gene Hackman", "Gwnyeth Paltrow", "Anjelica Huston"],
      runtime: 170,
    },
    "Fantastic Mr. Fox": {
      year: 2009,
      plot: "An urbane fox cannot resist returning to his farm raiding ways and then must help his community survive the farmers' retaliation.",
      cast: [
        "George Clooney",
        "Meryl Streep",
        "Bill Murray",
        "Jason Schwartzman",
      ],
      runtime: 147,
      rating: 7.9,
    },
    "The Grand Budapest Hotel": {
      rating: 8.1,
      runtime: 159,
      year: 2014,
      plot: "A writer encounters the owner of an aging high-class hotel, who tells him of his early years serving as a lobby boy in the hotel's glorious years under an exceptional concierge.",
      cast: ["Ralph Fiennes", "F. Murray Abraham", "Mathieu Amalric"],
    },
  };

  // Make use of .join method to display list nicely  
  document.getElementById("movie-list").innerHTML = Object.keys(movieData).join(", ");
  
  function dropDown() { // No parameter
    moviesDropDown.addEventListener('change', () => {
      // Look up selected value, and use it to retrieve the corresponding movie data 
      movieDetails.innerHTML = movieData[moviesDropDown.value].cast.join(", ");
    })
  }
  
  const movieDetails = document.getElementById('movie-details');
  
  const moviesDropDown = document.getElementById('movies-drop-down');
  for (let movieName in movieData) {
    let movieOptionElement = document.createElement("option");
    movieOptionElement.setAttribute('value', movieName); // Should not be object
    let movieOptionText = document.createTextNode(movieName);
    movieOptionElement.appendChild(movieOptionText);
    moviesDropDown.appendChild(movieOptionElement);
  };
  dropDown(); // Only one call -- no argument
```

```html
Movie list: <span id="movie-list"></span><br>
Select a movie: <select id="movies-drop-down"></select><br>
movie-details: <span id="movie-details"></span>
```